# Basis for sequence space

Tags: linear-algebra

In class, my professor mentioned that finding a basis for the sequence space $\mathbb{K}^\mathbb{N}$ is very difficult to do. I am confused about this, since wouldn’t the collection of sequences $\{e_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$, where  $e_i$ is the sequence with all entries $0$ except the $i$th element, which is $1$ be a basis for this space? I was able to sketch a quick proof that they span the space and are linearly independent.

Comment: What is $\mathbb K$?

Comment: @DonThousand it is an arbitrary field

Comment: Note that the basis must have a $\textit{finite}$ representation of any member of $\mathbb K^{\mathbb N}$

Comment: You can adapt an argument similar to Cantor's Diagonal Argument to prove that the basis of this space is uncountable, assuming $\mathbb K$ is not trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way to show that a sequence space can not have a countable basis: Consider the collection $\mathscr N$, of countably infinite subsets of $\mathbb N$, indexed by some set $\Lambda$ such that any two elements, say, $N_{\alpha}$  and $N_{\beta};\ \alpha,\beta\in \Lambda,$ have finite intersection. It is easy to see that $\mathscr N$ is uncountable, and that the sequences $\{\chi_{N_\alpha}:\alpha\in \Lambda\}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: This looks wrong, what about $\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2,3\}$? The corresponding set of indicators is linearly dependent

Comment: We are taking the members of $\mathscr N$ to be countably infinite.

Answer (score 5):

How do you display $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ in your basis?